# How do I remove the automatic new line when exporting from applescript to text file?

Tags: terminal, applescript, echo

If I was to the run command

`do shell script "echo hello > ~/Desktop/file.txt"`

It would generate a text file on my Desktop with the name file.txt and the contents

> hello
>
> > (Imagine a blank line here)

How can I keep it from creating this line, I am unable to find any resources online. Or is my online option to find some way to remove it after it is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it I believe:

```
do shell script "printf hello > ~/Desktop/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

DigiMonk's code works.

### But a note to future readers:

The original posters code :

```
do shell script "echo hello" > "~/Desktop/file.txt"
```

Is incorrectly posted and will never work as is.
Applescript will compile it. But in effect it is say 'is hello **greater than** ~/Desktop/file.txt

Correct forms:

Quote and escape the quotes for the text string. ( the better option if the text string is long and contains spaces.)

```
do shell script "echo \"hello world\" > ~/Desktop/file.txt"
```

or use no quotes.

```
do shell script "echo hello > ~/Desktop/file.txt"
```

Also note you cannot quote around the file path when using the tilde ~ symbol.
The tilde symbol is used to point to the users home directory. Quoting it will stop it working.

Comment: I had it quoted correctly, I just made the mistake when typing it in StackOverflow. I have it doing printf now and that works for me.

Comment: I guessed as much. And tried to edit your post. But some of the reviews bewilderingly seemed to think otherwise?? and rejected the edit. Hence my note to other readers who may try and use your code as posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
do shell script "printf %s " & quoted form of "hel'\\%slo" & " > ~/Desktop/file.txt"
```

`printf aa%sbb` would print `aabb`. This method doesn't work if the input is longer than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes (currently about 300 kB).

This also works for longer strings:

```
set f to POSIX file ((system attribute "HOME") & "/Desktop/file.txt") as text
set b to open for access f with write permission
set eof b to 0
write "α" to b as «class utf8»
close access b
```

Without `as «class utf8»` the file would be saved as MacRoman. `as Unicode text` is UTF-16.

`do shell script` uses /bin/sh, so `do shell script "echo -n hello"` prints `-n hello` unless you add `shopt -u xpg_echo`.

Comment: The text I am outputting is only one word, I output the varriables to a text file and then automatically read in the variables if they exist (If they don't the script prompts for them) when the script first runs.